# When i use firebase dynamic link in my flutter it opne app but not get link when app was kill

Tags: firebase, flutter, deep-linking

When my app run in background then i get link and it working fine but when my app was kill then i not get link when i open app from deep link.

here is my code for get link

**This is my edited code**

```
 void initDynamicLinks() async {
    FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink(
        onSuccess: (PendingDynamicLinkData dynamicLink) async {
          final Uri deepLink = dynamicLink?.link;

          if (deepLink != null) {
            print('---new deep link onLink**********************************${deepLink}');
            Fluttertoast.showToast(
                msg: "onLink handle    ${deepLink}",
                toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
                timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                textColor: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 16.0
            );
            //Navigator.pushNamed(context, deepLink.path);
          }
        },
        onError: (OnLinkErrorException e) async {
          print('onLinkError');
          print(e.message);
        }
    );

    final PendingDynamicLinkData data = await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
    final Uri deepLink = data?.link;

    if (deepLink != null) {
      print('---new deep found************************************************');
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: "get?Initial handle    ${deepLink}",
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
          gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
          timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          textColor: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 16.0
      );
     // Navigator.pushNamed(context, deepLink.path);
    }
  }
```

I call initPlatformState() for init and it working fine when my app is run in background.

How can i get url when my app is in force stop

**Now same problem onLink work but getInitialLink not work for first time open app from url**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set 2 sec delay for getInitialLink then it work.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the delay? where exactly do you implement the delay?
After the initState or in " FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink(... "?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you need to add 2-3 seconds delay on initiating + you can handle the deeplink out of (onSuccess). It worked for me finally!
Check this link below
https://betterprogramming.pub/deep-linking-in-flutter-with-firebase-dynamic-links-8a4b1981e1eb

Answer (score 1):

Where is your `FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();` and `FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink` logic?

It seems that you are only handling links while the app is in the backgroud via the stream.listen method, but the code you posted doesn't show the logic for handling links when the app is terminated.

Comment: I have only this in my app

Comment: As I said, the code you posted doesn't point to handling links while the app is isn't in the background, it's just doing exactly what you are telling it to do.

Comment: ok so when my app is in background then how to handle? please explain

Comment: please check my edited code in question now same issue onLink work but getInitialLink not work